# Grails inheritance wrong behavior

Tags: oop, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've noticed a very strange (or wrong) behavior on groovy OOP. I want to be sure that it is normal.
I have an interface and a class (in a grails project) like:

*Interface*

```
package it.rascio.test

interface MyInterface {
  public Object myMethod()

  public ArrayList<? extends Observable> secondMethod()
}
```

*Class*

```
package it.rascio.test

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Observable;

class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {

  @Override
  public Object myMethod() throws Exception{
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public ArrayList<String> secondMethod() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

}
```

How you can see this is conceptually wrong, because *myMethod* doesn't declare the *throws* clause while the class that implement the interface does

And the `secondMethod` want a `List` of `Observable` objects, but the implementing class declares a `List` of `String` (that isn't an `Observable`).

Using this code STS (eclipse) tells me that there are compile errors, BUT if I try to launch `grails compile` command, IT WORKS!

How is it possible? Is it a bug or what?

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Generics

Comment: So I shouldn't trust the eclipse compiler :D

Comment: Probably not ;-) What version of STS and Grails are you using?

Comment: STS 2.9.2.RELEASE and Grails 2.0.1

Comment: I don't use STS, so don't know if it's a known problem.  If you don't get a reply here, you could try [the SpringSource forum for STS](http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?32-SpringSource-Tool-Suite) or maybe post an [issue on their JIRA](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS)

Comment: I want to remove STS it 'cause more problems than how many it solves...I use it just because grails autoreload the classes just if I execute run-app inside STS

Comment: It auto-reloads if you run `grails run-app` from the command line too ;-)

Comment: I know...but I can't understand why it doesn't work for my project...I've seen that it doesn't recompile the classes when I modify them and the app is started using the command line...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18870/discussion-between-rascio-and-tim-yates)